# Crash in CoreData while saving data in from a backgroundthread

Tags: objective-c, ios, core-data, ios4, core-data-migration

I have a http request which is running in backgroundthread. As soon as the data arrives i am trying to save that into the coredata but it crashes randomly at many points with EXC_BAD_ACCESS error. Can somoeone point me to the right direction.

Comment: Please post a exact error message. The only thing we can tell you so far is: it is probably a problem with memory management in your code.

Comment: EXC_BAD_ACCESS(code= 2, address = 0x3423234) I got this error only when my background request is trying to save data in coredata

Comment: normally there is some text around it . can you post it too?

Comment: __NSArrayM release]: message sent to deallocated instance 0x859d5c0
 this text appears on console..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are properly releasing an array already released. Try enabling `NSZombie` or check if you are calling release on an array you did not create using the `alloc` keyword

Comment: the crash is quite random and this happens usually when i try to save data in core data from a request which runs as a background thread.

Comment: it could also be that you are missing a retain. Perhaps you could post your full code? (auto released object, gets released to early)

Comment: - (void)parseServiceResponse:(NSDictionary *)rawJSONData
{    
    // Clear out jsonData in case of subsiquent calls
    [self setJsonData:nil];
    [[CoreDataUtility sharedInstance] deleteAllObjectsForEntity:@"abcdata"];
    
    if (rawJSONData && [rawJSONData count]) {
        for (NSDictionary *bulk in rawJSONData) { 
            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(),^ {
                [Summary addSummaryData:bulk];
            } );
        }
                                                                                  I have written some routines which save the data in coredata

Comment: I Suspect this is an issue with background thread as from background thread i am trying to save data in main thread. I am not sure if this implementation is right?

Comment: I think your problem lays in your rawJsonData. Try calling [rawJSONData retain]; just before your for loop. NOTE: This approach will result in leaking rawJSONData and should only be used to test if this is really the problem!

Comment: Already checked that. But i strngly suspect the coredata issue here as i have 4 -5 threads are there which simulatnaeously trying to save the data in coredata table. i think this may be the problem but i don't know the solution for this.

Comment: that could very well be problematic, but I think you would get another error if that was the case. I think you should try enabling NSZombie and see what happens. Also, try taking a look at NSOperationQueue. You can then queue your inserts and only perform one at a time

Comment: now i am doing nsoperation 1 at a atime still its crashing at random points

Comment: Have you tried to enable NSZombies? I still think that is your problem. Click on your project name next to the stop button in Xcode and select Edit Scheme. Under diagnostics, check Enable Zombie Objects. See what the log contains when running...

Comment: already enabled zoombie? I think log here is console output.. It always comes as [__NSArrayM respondsToSelector:]: message sent to deallocated instance 0x10489900. Any more help?

Comment: are you absolutely sure you have enabled NSZombies?. You should not get[__NSArrayM respondsToSelector:]: message sent to deallocated instance 0x10489900 if so...

Comment: just checked again.. i enabled the zoombie for wrong project :(.. enabled it again for right 1 & checking again..

Comment: so do you see any information about the Zombies in the log now?

Comment: issue is fixed now. There was an overerelease object somewhere else which was causing the issue. thnxs CipraMill